# mysql create a table character sets

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

In phpmyadmin, I entered:

```
CREATE TABLE ch
 ucs2 CHAR(3) CHARACTER SET ucs2,
 gb2312 CHAR(3) CHARACTER SET gb2312
 test3 CHAR(4) CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

And it gives me a syntax error.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a table in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49536542/how-to-create-a-table-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgotten parentheses:

```
CREATE TABLE ch(
 ucs2 CHAR(3) CHARACTER SET ucs2,
 gb2312 CHAR(3) CHARACTER SET gb2312,
 test3 CHAR(4) CHARACTER SET utf8
);
```